# SQL query to insert the same record for all the ids of another table in a new table

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having two tables: notificattins and users

I want to insert one record into the notifications table for every record of the users table.

in fact i want to add one notification for every user to receive.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify your table structure but generally you can do this

```
insert into notifications (some_column, other_column)
select username, other_column
from users
```

Comment: thanks, nice job, before your code i tried to get all the users and then in a while loop inserted the msg into the notification table while the loop ended.